# Fedora Firewall not blocking http

Tags: fedora, http

I have a fedora machine running that I use for my daily work, mostly working on websites. Whenever I wanted to check something from another device within the local network, I had to first enable http in the firewall, but that is no longer the case. It seems any device that is connected to my router can now enter the i.p. of the fedora box, and get the requested content even when I explicitly disable http in the firewall config tool. Why is that? and how can I fix it? I want to disable http access from within the local network until I explicitly enable it via the firewall config tool.

Comment: what firewall interface are you configuring specifically (iptables, UFW, raw netfilter, etc)? have you allowed unsolicited traffic from your LAN, perhaps by ? if you allow the packet before your deny rule, it will come through.

Comment: I don't remember making any changes since before when it used to block http. The interface, i'm not sure. I click on the fedora menu > Administration > Firewall not sure if that uses iptables or what.

Comment: The firewall is working now... I don't even know why. I didn't change anything, and no one else did. I just woke up this morning, and wanted to test a site, and couldn't access it. I had to enable http on the firewall. I didn't even shut down my computer yesterday. I just put it to sleep. I don't know what is going on...